# Is there support of mass insertion with RedisJson?

Tags: python, redis, redisjson

I'm considering to use the mass insertion feature of the redis. Though did not find any references to do so.

Is there work arounds to use the [redis mass insert](https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) with [RedisJson](https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/)?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via the redis-cli like a standard mass insert

```
$ cat data.txt 
JSON.SET foo . '{"bar": "baz"}'
JSON.SET yo . '{"bar": "biz"}'

$ cat data.txt  | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 2

$ redis-cli JSON.GET yo
"{\"bar\":\"biz\"}"
```

If you are looking to do this via python use a Redis pipeline an [example](https://github.com/RedisJSON/redisjson-py#usage-example) is on the docs script for the driver.

I generally do something like:

```
rj = Client(host='localhost', port=6379, decode_responses=True)
pipe = rj.pipeline()

row_count = 0 
for x in mydata:
    pipe.jsonset(x[0], Path('.cost'), x[1])
    row_count += 1
    if row_count % 500 == 0:
        pipe.execute()

pipe.execute()
```

Comment: `JSON.SET foo . '{"bar": "baz"}'` Isn't valid json though..